# TV series about a young boy looking for glowing and spiky crystals

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am looking for a TV series that I watched around 2000 - 2005-ish. It was a sci-fi/ fantasy about a young boy traveling with his companions to some places, like caves or maybe other planets, and he was looking for some big glowing and spiky crystals. They were being chased by a dude in a robotic-like armor and helmet, so his face wasn't seen and the color may have been brown, I think. I remember that the dude eventually turned up good and they were betrayed by one of their own. The boy's group also had a creature companion, but I don't remember much about it, only that it was small. I also remember the end of the series - it ended that the boy like woke up or something and appeared in school with his school-mates being those companions.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Congratulations on identifying your work! Please don't feel that the question being marked as a duplicate is a reprimand or anything like that. It's basically just a way we have to index questions that turn out to be the same thing, to make it easier to get all of the information in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would lay odds you're looking for [*Josh Kirby... Time Warrior!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Kirby..._Time_Warrior!)

> The series concerns a device, found by humans in the 25th century, called the Nullifier. This device is said to be capable of destroying the universe. Realizing the danger, a man called Irwin 1138 splits the Nullifier into six pieces, which are then dispersed through time. However, a scientist called Dr. Zoetrope finds out where the pieces are located and, with the help of his time traveling armor, sets about reassembling the device. Along with 20th century teenager Josh Kirby, and a half-human warrior known as Azabeth Siege, Irwin 1138 sets about thwarting Dr. Zoetrope's plans.
>
> Josh Kirby is 14 years of age in 9th grade and his journey starts when he is accidentally pulled into the fight between Irwin and Zoetrope when a piece of the Nullifier lands in his time. He has to overcome his homesickness for small-town America, helped by befriending the alien warrior-girl Azabeth, and saving her life, a result of this being that she is bound by oath to protect him. After a series of adventures including seeing the year 70,379 where humans have become tyrannical giants, a world populated by living toys, and Azabeth’s home world where humans are the hated enemy of her people, The Kang, he eventually is confronted by a shocking betrayal by Irwin before he discovers that he must choose between Azabeth's survival and fulfilling his Time Warrior destiny.

Dr. Zooetrope does wear dark armor and they do pick up a creature companion played by a puppet. And yes, the "good guy" and "bad guy" turn out to not be who you expect.

And according to [this review](https://www.google.com/amp/s/djworralloart.tumblr.com/post/127656564525/josh-kirbytime-warrior-chapter-6-last-battle/amp), they do do the dream ending.

> So Josh goes back to his own time and…wait for it…he wakes up in bed the day that everything started. yes, the film ends with the “it was all a dream” ploy, with Josh doing things a little differently, such as while he is telling his friend Erwin, who we met in the first film  about his “dream” (Erwin is apparently Irwin’s great great great great etc grandfather according to Josh, must have missed that point…), and Josh is once again, as in the first film,  accosted by the school jock Duke, who asks Josh if he’s done his homework, however, a girl steps in and overpowers Duke, forcing him to retreat. Josh recognises Azabeth, but apparently she is Elizabeth Kang,a student who just transferred to the school, and the film whimsically ends as Josh and Elizabeth head to the school canteen and hold hands as they go despite apparently having only just met.